# Fatfree framework - create instance of class in another class construct method

Tags: php, oop, fat-free-framework

404 error while executing code below. The Class 'MagazineModel' extends Controller like Class 'Magazine'. Qestion is: Cant i create object of 'MagazineModel' in Class 'Magazine'?
If i cant, how can i do that in different way? Thanks for help!

```
Class Magazine extends Controller
{
public $id;
public $name;
public $logo_path;
public $order;
public $description;

//model instance container
public $magazine_model;


public function __construct() 
{
   parent::__construct();

//properties from model
   if (class_exists('MagazineModel')) {

       $this->magazine_model = new MagazineModel();

   }
}
public function getId() 
{
    return $this->id;
}

public function getName() 
{
   return $this->name;
}
public function getLogoPath() 
{
    return $this->logo_path;
}
public function getOrder() 
{
    return $this->order;
}
public function getDescription() 
{
    return $this->description;
}
public function testShow()
{
echo $this->twig->render('index.html.twig');
}
}
```

Comment: Why would a model extend a controller base class? Anyway please provide the full error stack. Also what version of f3 are you using.

Comment: Thank You very much. It works.. Can You tell me why it doesnt work if extends Controller?